# unable to create Google calendar Event using java

Tags: java, google-chrome, google-calendar-api

I use Google oauth playground.I get access token and try to create event using Java code but from some email Ids I am able to create but for other emails id it gives :

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.techjini.university.utils.GoogleUtils.createUpdateEvent(GoogleUtils.java:160)
```

This exception at this line of code

```
event = getCalendarService(accessToken).events().insert("primary", event).execute();
            System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getId());
            createList.add(event.getId());
```

I am not able to get calendarId  please suggest what wrong with this one or any permission thing we have to set in calendar but some of email id I am able to create event.

Comment: As the [401 unauthorized](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials) error suggests, the access token is probably expired/invalid. I can't say for sure since I haven't tried it before, but AFAIK, tokens from the OAuth Playground can't be used for actual requests outside of it. Could you try [get an access token](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) (not through the Playground) and see if that makes it work?

Comment: but some other machine with differnt acess token we are able to create event  but from email acess token i am not able to create  get 401 exception@AL.